# rails 3.2.0 skip before filter only if it is a json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
1. skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:index,:show], :if => proc {|c| request.json?}

2. skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:index,:show], :if => :format_json?

    def format_json?
      request.format.json?
    end   

3. skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:index, :show] , :if =>request.content_type == "json"
for the first request it is showing:
    #undefined local variable or method `request' for ExamsController:Class
If i refresh the page it is not skipping anyting
```

I want to skip authentication for "index" and "show" actions only if request content is json. I have tried above examples but nothing is working. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
class XXXXController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:index,:show], if: :json_request?

  #your other actions here. 

  private 
  def json_request?
    request.format.symbol == :json
  end
end
```

In my case I tried with following call to my action & the format is verified to be of :json type:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){

   $('body').on('submit', '#new_job', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: '/jobs/',
      type: 'post',
      success: function(data){
        console.log("registered success");
      },
      failure: function(error){
        console.log("This is the failure block ");
      }
    });
   });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but Its not working. It is skipping :authorize for all format. Is it allowed to skip authentication for a specific format in rails 3.2.0 ?

Comment: I am having a warning "WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
" . This might cause any problem?

Comment: well in my case it's not showing any such warning. Would you please share your piece of code where you are sending json request type..

Comment: @HabibullahAraphatKonok, Ih ave updated my answer . See this is how I send my json type of request & verify the same in before_action. 
Please share the code section which part is sending your json type of request.

Comment: Thanks @martin
After some trial and error the following code is working for me. I am not sure though what is problem in this approach. 
`before_filter :authorize, :except => [:index,:show]`
`before_filter(:only => [:index,:show]) do |controller|`
 `authorize unless controller.request.format.json?`
`end`

Comment: okay, it's alternatively pointing to the same solutions. Good to know, it fixed up your issue. 
Let me update the answer, that might help to any other person. :)

Answer (score 3):

This should fix it

`skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:index,:show], :if => Proc.new {|c| c.request.format.json?}`

You needed to do Proc.new and then use the local variable c and access the format.

Answer (score 0):

For rails 3 you want to do it like this

```
class XXXXController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authorize, if: :public_request?

  #your other actions here. 

  private
  def public_request?
    # action_name is a rails method that returns the requested action
    public_action = (action_name == 'show' or action_name == 'index' )
    return ( public_action and request.format.symbol == :json )
  end
end
```